# Negation with an appositive containing multiple elements

Tags: conjunctions, negation, appositives

> 1. I don't like the names Axel **and** Brook.
> 2. I don't like the names Axel **or** Brook.
> 3. I don't like the name Axel, and I don't like the name Brook.
> 4. I don't like the name Axel or the name Brook.

Which is better, 1 or 2?

The intended meaning is that of 3 and I know 4 has the same meaning as 3. However, the fact that in 1 and 2 there are two elements functioning together as an appositive is confusing me. Do the same rules of negation apply as in 4?

Comment: 2 is correct; 1 is not.

Comment: There is no apposition in your examples.

Comment: @Lambie If _the name Axel_ is not apposition, what is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apposition means naming the same thing in a different way, set off by commas.

**Axel and Brook, the best players on the team**, were brothers. That would be apposition or an appositive.

That said, all the examples in the question are grammatical. None contains an apposition.

In your examples, the words are direct objects.

[An appositive is a word or phrase that restates or redefines a nearby noun.](http://web.colby.edu/farnham-writerscenter/grammar-tips/dashes/)

Comment: Thank you. Do you agree with @JasonBassford that 2 is better than 1?

Comment: @silverpepper Yes, it is better.